# How to programmatically select multiple rows in QListView?

Tags: qt

I have written a program where the user can select multiple rows from a QListView. Sometimes the program need to load a set of selection at startup, so the program needs to be able to select multiple rows from code. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

you can use QItemSelectionModel class to manage the view selection and modify them.

from document :

> Whenever you want to modify the selected items use select() and provide either a QItemSelection, or a QModelIndex and a QItemSelectionModel::SelectionFlag.